# match_parent when parent is wrap_content?

Tags: android, xml, material-design

I'm pretty new to Android development. I'm trying to add a colored rectangle to fill the height of a `CardView`. Here's my XML.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <View android:id="@+id/color_bar"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#673AB7" />

             ...

        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

However, the bar is not appearing in the card. It doesn't seem to be getting the height of the card for `match_parent` (If I hard code in the height in dp, it displays). Is this due to the fact the card's height is set to `wrap_content` or is it something entirely different? I'm on API 16.

EDIT: Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: An image showing what I'm trying to achieve]

However this was done with hard coded dp values and doesn't scale to devices. I'm trying to make this bar adapt to the card size.

Comment: You cannot specify conflicting layout params. If the child has match_parent and the parent has wrap_content, there's a cycle.

Comment: @Zielony I see. That makes sense. How would I go about achieving my goal another way?

Comment: I guess you can put height of color_bar in dp (like 50dp) and height of `RelativeLayout` as `wrap_content`. It should work

Comment: @bipin The problem is that I also have text (thus the wrap_content), and the bar doesn't scale to accommodate, meaning on many devices the bar is either too long or too short.

Comment: If you want to have a View (the bar) close to a CardView, just swap the containers: The RelativeLayout will contain the CardView AND the View, one close to the other one.

Comment: @DerGolem I'm not quite sure I understand. Put the View outside of the card?

Comment: Yes, **near** to it. RelativeLayout offers the ability of positioning the Views in relation to each other, say `android:toLeftOf="@id/card_view"` (this goes in your View). Obviously, it has to be set **after** the CardView (or it won't find the CardView **id**)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe nest in a `LinearLayout` and use `weight`?

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CarView
    ...>

    <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:orientation="horizontal">
         <View
             android:layout_width="0dp"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:layout_weight="10"
             android:background="#67BA37"/>
         <RelativeLayout
             android:layout_width="0dp"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:layout_weight="100"
             ...>
             ...
          </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Not very flat but seems to work